# What's the cheapest way to get from downtown Taoyuan to downtown Taipei, other than hitchhiking?

Tags: budget, transportation, taiwan, taipei

I will probably hitchhike but it is winter and rain is not unlikely.

There are lots of discussions about getting from Taoyuan airport to Taipei, but I've actually been staying in Taoyuan for a few days. I'm quite close to Taoyuan station.

I don't care about speed or efficiency. I'm in no hurry. I'm just looking for the cheapest way to get to Taipei. I'm guessing it would be the regular (non-HSR) train, or perhaps a private bus company.

If it makes a difference I'll be heading to the area around "Small South Gate".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're correct; Taoyuan station to Taipei station is **52 TWD** by local train, or about US$1.60.

There is also the recently opened Taoyuan MRT Subway service via the airport, but this doesn't cover the old Taoyuan station (only the new HSR one) and is much pricier at 160 TWD.

Comment: I've checked with my hosts in Taoyuan, and even though buses from here to Taipei are frequent, they actually cost more than the train, though I don't have prices. I guess they stop here along longer routes and some may choose them because they might have a stop that's handier for them than any of the train stations.

Answer (score 3):

> If you get a "normal train" a PuTong (Kuai) ticket from Taipei main
> station to Taoyuan station the price is 31 Taiwan dollars. You may be
> allowed to board any train with this ticket but legally you are only
> allowed to board the slow train that stops at every stop.
>
> The answer is $31NTD on a stopping service.
>
> Go to [this
> website](https://www.railway.gov.tw/tra-tip-web/tip/tip001/tip114/query)
> to check.

EDIT: actually, looking on the website shows that the putong kuai train left service in 2020 except for selected tourist routes. the next cheapest train would be the qujian or qujian kuai (fast) train at $42 taiwan dollars for an adult and $21 twd for a child or pensioner.